# In JS: Better way to say "if var1 is greater than var0 then assign var1 to var0"

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the code:

```
if (votes > tmp) tmp = votes;
```

It does what it says on the tin: `if var1 > var0 then var0 = var1`

Is there a cleaner way to write this in Javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: I agree. This is the most readable version - the code itself reads exactly as what you're describing, which is a good thing.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any cleaner way of doing this.  The code, as written, is cheap (avoids assignment when unnecessary) and is also very easy to understand.  Trying to be clever will actually cost you readability *and* performance (a very small amount) in this case.

Comment: My recommendation: `if ( votes > tmp ) { tmp = votes; }` I believe this is slightly more readable than your original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Math.max` if you feel it's cleaner...

```
tmp = Math.max(votes, tmp)
```

---

A comment below seems to suggest that you need the max of an Array.

If so, you can do this...

```
tmp = Math.max.apply(null, votes);
```

Or if you need to include the current `tmp` value, you can concat it in...

```
tmp = Math.max.apply(null, votes.concat(tmp));
```

Comment: @nc3b: The question defines "better" as "cleaner". There's an element of subjectivity.

Comment: @nc3b well it's marginally more functional.  Any "what's better" question is likely to be subjective of course.

Comment: This code is more compact, but is (I think) a bit harder to understand, and will execute an assignment regardless of whether the value in `tmp` will change.  The OP's code is IMO the cleanest and cheapest way of doing this.

Comment: @nc3b, it requires less thinking on the part of a code reader and if `isNaN(votes)`, `Math.max` does not silently ignore the problem.

Comment: @cdhowie: I certainly agree with you that OP's code will be cheaper in most, if not all, browsers.

Comment: @nc3b It's more semantic to me in that it says `tmp` should be the larger of the 2 values, but it is a subjective call.

Comment: Just note that this solution is only equal in case both are real numbers. It will have different behaviour in case of other values, including `NaN`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel "Requires less thinking". Seriously ? I know I'm in the js tag but is an `if` that big an issue ?

Comment: @pimvdb: The `NaN` result may be preferred (as an indicator that something is wrong) over the `false` result that `>` will give you. But you're right, it isn't strictly equal behavior.

Comment: @nc3b, Yes.  You have to think about the exact semantics of `<` and wonder what happens when strings like "3" reach it.  With `Math.max`, you can assume coercion to numerics, and know that special values like `NaN` are preserved.  `Math.max` just gets the numeric corner cases right.  Hand-rolled conditionals often do not.

Comment: @pimvdb, I agree.  Preserving `NaN` is the right thing to do 99% of the time.  Any intentional laundering or reinterpreting of `NaN` deserves a comment.

Comment: Ah, I am, but this does not work for >= I.E.8, so I feature detect 'Array.max' with `if ([].max)` then do the above code for >= I.E.8.

Comment: @JonathonDavidOates: This is not a method of `Array.prototype`. This is on the standard `Math` object. Are you needing to use this on an Array? And did you mean it doesn't work `<= IE8`?

Comment: Yes, I mean <= I.E.8. I also mean `Array.map`.

Comment: I can't believe Microsoft wasn't even able to implement `Math.max` in IE8. Otherwise you can easily write your own.

Comment: @pimvdb: It is supported [according to this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dxcwky7y(v=vs.94).aspx). I can't test it right now, but I'm certain I've used it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = (votes > tmp) ? [RESULT IF TRUE] : [RESULT IF FALSE];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you could write `tmp = Math.max(tmp,votes);`, but there's no real reason for using that over the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = (votes > tmp) ? votes : tmp;
```